# Nested radical eventually reaches 1

Tags: radicals, infinity, nested-radicals

Can anyone prove / disprove$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}}}}}}}} = 1$ for all $n>0$?

$\infty \sqrt{  }s $

---

Note: This is my first question here. Any constructive feedback is welcomed. If you are wondering, this is not a piece of homework, but a problem I encountered when trying to solve a problem in [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions). Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to be more precise here. There's no accepted definition for applying a function infinitely many times. You could instead define $a_0 = n$ and $a_m = \sqrt{a_{m-1}}$ for all $m \ge 1$ (i.e. $a_m$ is the result of applying the square root function $m$ times to $n$), and then compute the limit. This limit will indeed equal $1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit sorry i don't get what you mean. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that by such an expression with "infinitely many radicals" you really mean the limit as the number of radicals goes to infinity. (But, you *really really* shouldn't use notation like this without being precise about what it means.)

Given that, the answer is indeed $1$ for any $n>0$.  If you iterate taking the square roots $m$ times starting from $n$, that gives you $n^{1/2^m}$.  As $m\to\infty$, the exponent converges to $0$, and so since the function $x\mapsto n^x$ is continuous, $n^{1/2^m}$ converges to $n^0=1$.

Comment: thanks! that helped a lot